# Need of drivers during installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Do I need to install drivers after installing Ubuntu? Like we need to install drivers when we install Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Ubuntu comes with all (open source) drivers already installed.
The drivers are getting installed during the Ubuntu system installation.
When you want to install proprietary drivers alternatively, you can do it.
It is recommended mainly for NVIDIA graphics and some wireless cards.
You can select them from Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates.

[image]